# GitLab API not listing all image repositories in container registry

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I've pushing Docker images to my GitLab Container Registry using a CI pipeline for a while now and I've been using this command to list all repositories (20 repos) inside my registry:

```
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN:  $GITLAB_TOKEN" "$CI_SERVER_PROTOCOL://$CI_SERVER_HOST/api/v4/projects/$PROJECT_ID/registry/repositories"
```

I've created 5 new repositories using my CI, and I can see all repos in GitLab's interface (25 repos), but the command is only returning 20 repositories.

What could be the reason for this?

Comment: check [Gitlab API Pagination](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/README.html#pagination). 20 is the default number of items to list per page

Comment: @NicolasPepinster Thank you a lot, I'll accept it as an answer !

Answer (score 3):

20 is the default number of items to list per page with Gitlab API.

You can either change the number of item `per_page` (but the max is 100) or iterate over result using Pagination Link header. Detailed explanation can be found in the [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/README.html#pagination).